# python dont change rename columns

Tags: python, pandas

After calculating the data output to the data frame, if the columns of the output data are blank,
The rename function is not working.

```
    time
2022-03-30 22:45:00          NaN
2022-03-30 22:46:00          NaN
2022-03-30 22:47:00          NaN
2022-03-30 22:48:00          NaN
2022-03-30 22:49:00          NaN
                         ...    
2022-03-31 15:20:00    43.937125
2022-03-31 15:21:00    42.781336
2022-03-31 15:22:00    43.228084
2022-03-31 15:23:00    48.822237
2022-03-31 15:24:00    58.590912
Name: close, Length: 1000, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

---

What should I do if I want to put my name in the line next to time?

Comment: what is your code which failed?

Comment: I extracted some columns from the data frame and calculated them and printed the results.

Comment: If Name : close, isn't the normal blank close?

Comment: this is Series and it has name `close`. Better show code which make problem and add example data so we could run and see problem.  At  this moment you doesn't show `DataFrame` with columns but only single `Series` which has name `close`. So I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expected result is:

```
                  time      close
0  2022-03-30 22:45:00        NaN
1  2022-03-30 22:46:00        NaN
2  2022-03-30 22:47:00        NaN
3  2022-03-30 22:48:00        NaN
4  2022-03-30 22:49:00        NaN
5  2022-03-31 15:20:00  43.937125
6  2022-03-31 15:21:00  42.781336
7  2022-03-31 15:22:00  43.228084
8  2022-03-31 15:23:00  48.822237
9  2022-03-31 15:24:00  58.590912
```

You just have to use `df.reset_index()` because the dataset above is not a `DataFrame` but a `Series`. If you want to keep `time` as index, you can use `df.to_frame()` or `df.to_frame('new_name')`.